# sqlplus connection string issues

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a sql connection string that looks like

```
 echo $SQLSTR    
 sys/<pwd>@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxx)(INSTANCE_NAME=xxxx))) AS SYSDBA"
```

I was able to connect through

```
sqlplus -s /nolog  << EOF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 99
connect ${SQLSTR}
EOF
```

I could not succeed in putting the connection outside the file. I have tried with 2 options, and they are not working for me. Wanted to get some help fixing this

```
sqlplus "${SQLSTR}" >  $log << EOF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK
....
EOF

SQLSTR2="\"$SQLSTR\""
sqlplus "${SQLSTR2}" >  $log << EOF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK
....
EOF
```

Comment: First question is why are you connecting as SYS in this scenario? That account should only be used for things like startup and shutdown, or for patch installation. Second question is why would you expose your user credentials - and especially the SYS credentials - in the command line or as an environment variable, where almost any OS user can see and copy it? This approach is really, really, *really* insecure. What is the larger problem that you are trying to solve here with these scripts?

Comment: It is a very specific use case. the script is used for creating schema, adding tables, tablespaces, indexes. the credentials will be read from a separate configuration file.

Comment: Connecting as SYSDBA is still not appropriate for most DDL interactions; always connect as the actual schema owner. Use an Oracle Wallet (aka Secure External Password Store) to hold credentials - it is purpose-built to do that securely; then you don't have to pull *anything* into your script.